How to connect postgresql vercel in navicat
enter image description here
enter image description here
ERROR: The endpoint ID is not specified. Either upgrade the Postgres client library (libpq) for SNI support or pass the endpoint ID (the first part of the domain name) as a parameter: '&options=endpoint%3D'. See https://neon.tech/sni for more information.
i fill out all of fields but not working

This is what actually works for me.
First. In the password field put the following:
endpoint=<endpoint_id>;<your_password>

Being a password field its not easy to see what you type. Best write it somewhere else first, then copy and paste to avoid typos.
Second. In the SSL tab, check the SSL checkbox and select "require" from the SSL dropdown below.

Try change your password to this:
<endpoint_id>;<your_password>

